# React + Webpack: process.env is EMPTY after run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs

A common problem but as usual, every solution found on this website, not fit my case.

I've create a .env.production file with specific constant.

In my package.json I have:

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js --colors",
```

I run the build with the classic: `npm run build`

This is my webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

var config = {
context: __dirname + '/src',
entry: {
    javascript: "./index.js",    
},

output: {
  // path:path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
  path: path.join(__dirname,'../static/js/'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
},

devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
},
 resolveLoader: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        query: {
           presets: ['react']
        }
     },
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },
     {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "react-svg-loader",
            options: {
              jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
   },
  }

 module.exports = config;
```

As you can see, Im not overriding ENV in webpack config using the `webpack.DefinePlugin` plugin.

So why my process.env is EMPTY?

When I start the app with npm start, the process.env is normally filled and `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to development.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what about `.babelrc` ?

Comment: @Aaqib May you be more specific?